# Stata rnormal()

Tags: random, stata

I want to generate a fixed random variable `~N(0,10)` for every observation for future computation.

```
gen X=rnormal (0,10)
list X

Blank
```

How can I see what value of `X` is being generated?

Answer (score 2):

You were probably using an empty dataset when you issued these commands. In that case you would first need to tell Stata how many observations your dataset contains. For that you need to use the `set obs` command, so something like:

```
. set seed 12345

. set obs 10
obs was 0, now 10

. gen x = rnormal(0,10)

. list, clean

               x  
  1.   -9.580833  
  2.   -2.907274  
  3.     8.45202  
  4.    8.617108  
  5.   -12.19151  
  6.    9.457337  
  7.    1.722469  
  8.   -13.29949  
  9.    -11.5291  
 10.     25.1646
```

Think of what would happen when you did not use `set obs`. In that case Stata would see `gen x = rnormal(0,10)` and think "ok, I need to create random draws from a normal distribution, but how many?". If you had a dataset open, then it would answer "as many as there are observations in the dataset". If you had no dataset open, then the answer would still be "as many as there are observations in the dataset", but that happens to be 0.

---

**Edit:**

If you just want one number you are best of using scalars and not variables. In Stata a scalar refers to a single number and a variable refers to a single column in your dataset. For scalars it is best to use temporary names, as they share the same namespace as variables but variables take precedence when it comes to abreviations, which can lead to unexpected behaviour. So you could do something like:

```
. tempname a

. scalar `a' = rnormal(0,10)

. di `a'
10.737423
```

Comment: Thanks.
What if I need one constant/fixed X to do further computation later?
For instance, generate a new number based on that constant X, e.g. y=rnormal(x,5) ?? 
I did not want so many X.......

Comment: The last question seems to call for scalars. But it also seems confused. Why create a random number to use for later computation? Just create one when it is needed.

Comment: Thanks Buis and Cox, I just go to use Stata for programming purpose yesterday. I read possible tutorial material from Google but that was the first time I encountered "Scalar" !
Any recommended material just for programming (not for regression/statistic analysis)?

Comment: Chapter 18 of the User's Guide that comes with Stata. In fact the entire User's guide is full of good stuff. Also see: http://www.statapress.com/books/introduction-stata-programming/ and http://www.stata.com/netcourse/programming-intro-nc151/

Comment: In addition to Maarten's good advice: `search scalar` is an example of what you can type, i.e. `search` followed by a keyword. In general, look at Stata's own on-line documentation before Googling or sending questions to any forum or list.